# Clone div element and manipulate the original element and the clone with the same button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a element with three sub element `element1`, `element2` and `element3`.

When I use a command `button1` a filter `element1` 
When I use command `button2` filter `element2`

How I can clone this element 
and manipulate **"clone element and the original at same time"** this with the command `button1`

I use this code, but not work.

```
</script>
  <input type="button" id="btnClone" value="Clone Div" />
  <script>
      $("#btnClone").bind('click', function() {
          $('#prueban2').clone(true).appendTo('body');
      });
</script>
```

in other words how i can use the original button for manipulate the original element in his clone

Comment: Working for me, although your question is a little fuzzy. Can you clarify exactly what you mean by clone AND MANIPULATE ORIGINAL ELEMENT. See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/oou6d2s0/

Comment: example first button "THE COMMANDER" this use for filter in my code this filter only affect the original element not affect the clone

Comment: in other words how i can use the original button for manipulate the original element in his clone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undestood you right, just make a clone of element and then use `.add()` method to make jquery selection of both original and cloned element, then do everything you would like.

So I would made your code look like following:

```
<input type="button" id="btnClone" value="Clone Div" />
  <script>
      $("#btnClone").bind('click', function() {
          var $original = $('#prueban2');
          var $clone = $original.clone(true);
          $clone.appendTo('body');

          // now manipulate original element with clone:
          $original.add($clone).bind('click', function() { /* ... */ });

          // ... or:
          $original.add($clone).each(function(el) { /* ... */ });
      });
</script>
```

**Addition**

To manipulate two elements without cloning, you need to have them already existing. You can create these two elements with HTML (or PHP, etc.) and hide one of them (e.g. adding css class `.hidden` with `display:none`) until the `#btnClone` is clicked:

HTML:

```
<div id="preuban2"></div>
<div id="preuban2-1" class="hidden"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#btnClone').click(function() {
    $('#preuban2-1').removeClass('hidden');

    // manipulate both elements
    $('[id^=preuban2]').bind('click', function(){ /*...*/ });
}
```

Comment: yes i think that this is well , but not exist any way of do this without clone the button  only manipulate the two elements (the original and the clone) with the original button

Comment: @braveheart, other way is to pre-define both elements in your html. Check out the **addition** in my answer for details. If you cannot change the html - then cloning sounds like the best way.